# Laravel Query Builder error >7000 record

Tags: laravel-4

I have many record in table name `AE_MKT` (7500 record and more in the future)

and I use `Query Builder`

`$query  = DB::table('AE_MKT')->get();`

so I get error see on this image:
[image: MyImage]

and another config at the `.htaccess`

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
    Header append Cache-Control s-maxage=600 "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 200"
    Header set Connection keep-alive
```

but still error when I need query with large records

Comment: Why do you think cache control headers have anything to do with fetching DB records ?

Comment: Perhaps because a .htaccess file containing errors would cause a 500 error. Without looking at the logs or knowing if other pages/controllers work, it could potentially be such that all pages 500 because of bad syntax. That said, it seems unlikely and that the abridged bit of the file in the question looks ok.